# Getting variable from function with counter

Tags: javascript, scope

I setup a simple checkout with increment/subtract buttons (function calculates total price -> price * quantity) and now struggling getting the variable with the total amount out of that function. As a result I need the total amount (in the functions it's total1 or total2) in the global variable total. In my example it doesn't work, because calling the function incr() or subt() for the variable total triggers the function and adds or increment the value of the value again. This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
var quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var counter = document.getElementById("qty").value;

// subtract function triggered by subtract button
function subt(){
var quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value = --counter;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Total ' + quantity * 298 + ".-";
var total1 = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = quantity * 298;
return total1;
}

// increment function triggered by increment button
function incr(){
var quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value = ++counter;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Total ' + quantity * 298 + ".-";
var total2 = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = quantity * 298;
return total2;
}


var total = incr();

</script>
```

Comment: You have two methods that are basically the same thing, only difference is -- vs ++. Better to pass in -1 or 1 so you do not have to duplicate code.

Comment: So why are you not just updating the global varaible inside of your method?

Comment: @ChrisLi it is valid, hard to read, but valid.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, you mean to set two counters, one -1 and the other 1? Don't I then still need two functions to assign it to the two buttons?

Comment: `function update(dir) { 
counter+=dir;
} update(-1); update(1);`

Answer (score 0):

I think @epascarello means to create one function that get's a parameter passed to it [-1 or 1] in this case depending on if the add or subtract button is pressed.

I've been taught that you should avoid solutions using parameterless functions with no options it creates long drawn out code.

Example below:

```
var total = null;
addFoo.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  total = calcFunc(1);
});
minusFoo.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  total = calcFunc(-1);
});
function calcFunc(operation) {
  quantity = operation < 0 ? --counter : ++counter;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Total ' + quantity * 298 + ".-";
 var total = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = quantity * 298;
 return total;
```

}

I'm not quite sure what this is going to do though... :(
Is this what you had in mind @epascarello?

Comment: Thanks @StevenVanSant I tried it but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok, now the function itself works, sorry, I forgot to set the counter variable first...  Thanks for your help! But sadly I still have the problem that the variable _total_ only gets the value for running the calcFunc once (aka one click on increment button). But I want to have the updated value. For e.g. when button is clicked five times _total_ still returns only one increment iteration. Also at first load the function runs once and increases the counter, which I don't want...

Comment: The last one...at the end of the script you call   

    var total = calcFunc()  

removing that may stop it from executing the function

Comment: The first one, is most likely because you get the `counter` total at first execution instead of when the function is called during the event.  Do you need an example?

Comment: It's a scoping problem with when you updated the counter variable last...I might think at least.

Comment: For the last one: how do I get then var total without var total = calcFunc()? 
The first one: yes, this is the problem, but I don't know how to code it. An example would be nice, sure.

Comment: would it be safe to say that you could not use the calcFunc() to get the initial total? Because if you can than you can declare the total variable, with a start number if you already know it, rather than using the update when the code gets executed.

Comment: Yes, correct. What I did now is to hardcode the initial amount, not state of the art but this works for showing the initial number. But now unfortunately I still not get the var total outside of the function. I need it for making the charge with Stripe. But thanks so far, I really appreciate that.

Comment: I put in an edit to the events, so that the return value of the calcFunc() gets assigned to the total variable.

Comment: Your edit did the trick, thank you very much, I learned something today!

Comment: No worries, remember to utilize global scoped variables to optimize and simplify :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what my code looks now:

```
var counter = 1;
var quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var initial = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Total ' + quantity * 298 + ".-";
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var sub = document.getElementById("sub");
add.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  calcFunc(1);
});
sub.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  calcFunc(-1);
});
function calcFunc(operation) {
 quantity = operation < 0 ? --counter : ++counter;
 document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Total ' + quantity * 298 + ".-";
 var total = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = quantity * 298;
 return total;
}
```